# How to process previous, instant and next buffer with pyaudio to do overlapping?

Tags: python, pyaudio

I'd like to implement an overlapping in my audiostreaming. I use pyaudio module and Python 3. I have a filter function (it's a third octave band bank filter implemented with scipy.signal.filtfilt and Tchebychev type 2 designed filters).
My filter function works well but I have some glitch between each buffer when I stream my wavfile : some "clip noises" between each buffer. I think that is side effects which arise from the filter function. 
So I want to cancel it with window processing. The problem is the effect of window, I listen an increase and decrease of signal gain according to the window. 
Finally, I think to do overlapping so I need to know the previous buffer, the instant buffer and the next buffer and then I could windowing each buffer and summing them to rebuild the instant buffer and stream it.

My question is : How can I access to previous buffer and next buffer with pyaudio callback mode ?